# How to spilt text on textarea using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, interpreter

What I want to do is to split a string in a textarea when a certain character is meet.

I am using jQuery and still now I what I have achieved is that I can split text on white space and catch each substrings. Here is the example I have build:

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ofL1c1xo/)

Now I want to split the text not only when the whitespace is meet but also when the "=" sign is meet. So for example if I write at the input text area:

```
number =5
```

I will have the output

```
number
=5
```

But I want to have:

```
number
=
5
```

How can I achieve this? Thank you in advance

Comment: It can be javascript too, or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
var sublines = lines[i].split(" ");
```

To:

```
var sublines = lines[i].replace("=", " = ").split(/[\s]+/);
```

Comment: Thank you @Shane. It works... But what if i have number= 5 or number=5 and I want in the three cases to have the same output?

Comment: Updated original post. Added a regular expression that splits on any amount of white space. https://jsfiddle.net/ofL1c1xo/6/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#hi').val().split(/\b(\n|\=)\b/);
```

**DEMO**: https://jsfiddle.net/ofL1c1xo/2/

Comment: `number =5` does not convert to each on a separate line like the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("your_text_area").val().replace(/=/g, "\r\n=\r\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery aside, once you have a reference to the text, you can easily split it using:

```
"number  =10".replace(/([^\w 0-9])/g, "$1\n").replace(/\s+/g, "\n").split("\n")
```

Output (Array):

```
[0]: "number"
[1]: "="
[2]: "10"
```

This converts all white space to a line break (assuming you don't want to keep any white space), and puts a line break after all non-words and numbers.

Comment: Thank @ James. The idea is that I want to save each substring on a vector (sublines[j]) and to use them later for other thing. And I want to catch the substring where the white space or "=" is appeared...

Answer (score 0):

With a simple replace function:
https://jsfiddle.net/ofL1c1xo/8/

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function () {
    var lines = $('#hi').val(),
        output = lines.replace(/\s/g,"\n").replace("=","=\n");    
    $("#output").html(output);
});
```

[Update](https://jsfiddle.net/ofL1c1xo/10/), to make sure there are never more than one new line:

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function () {
    var lines = $('#hi').val(),
        output = lines.replace(/\s/g,"\n").replace("=","\n=\n").replace(/\n+/g,"\n");    
    $("#output").html(output);
});
```